# How can I implement tabs with RecyclerView

Tags: android, tabs, android-recyclerview

Currently I have a RecyclerView which upon creation is populated by a list of movies stored in an SQLite DB. Every movie has a genre that can be set by the end user.

I want to be able to set-up dynamic tabs for each genre that users can swipe through for easier access as the dataset grows. I was just at a loss for where to start. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`TabLayout` is where you should start.

You can use `addTab()` for dynamic tab creation.

`TabLayout` is made to work well with `ViewPager`.  When you use the `setupWithViewPager()` method, the two are set up with corresponding event listeners, so that swiping in the `ViewPager` sets the tab active, and selecting the tab goes to that tab's page in the `ViewPager`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can start with ViewPager and use RecyclerView in its fragments.